# Vagrant - access via browser without port in url?

Tags: vagrant, host, portforwarding

Some website can't work when accessing guest machine from host if there is port number in URL, (e.g. localhost:8080). I want to access website on guest machine via browser without port number in URL, for example vagrant.localhost.

Is there possibility to access website on guest machine via browser without port in URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to forward guest port 80 to host port 80 in order to achieve this.

Keep in mind that it will probably work **only** on Windows hosts, since Linux and Mac OS X both require root privileges to forward to ports < 1024.

Given this, the configuration instructions for doing the above port forwarding is:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 80
```

Then after `vagrant up` you can access to the website using `http://localhost`. If instead you want to use a different name, you have to create an entry in your `hosts` file pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Just to add, I actually tried this a few days ago on my OSX machine and I was able to map to 80.  Just had to provide sudo password for it to bind.  But it worked.  BUT you will not be able to use localhost or 127.0.0.1.  If you bind to 80 you should do the private network setup for vagrant and then use the ip to connect (like 192.168.2.30 or what ever you choose).  I did that, mapped it with a nice name in my /etc/hosts file, and was good to go.